# Integrated webcam is not sending back image

Tags: usb, kubuntu, dell, webcam, inspiron

**Final Update: I ran some hardware tests without booting into the OS and it seems that it's a purely hardware problem (some internal connections may broke off), thus this question is now *closed***

Whenever I launch `cheese` (or similar programs), the light on the webcam lights up, but no images were sent back.

My hardware is a Dell Inspiron 14-3442, and software Kubuntu 20.04

Here are output of some commands:

- `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:670b Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 24ae:2010 RAPOO Rapoo 2.4G Wireless Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I suppose that `0c45:670b` is the camera, but it seems that this has been supported in the kernel since the 2.x era.

Verbose output (`lsusb -v`) [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zgvbBS6Scc/)

- `dmesg | grep usb`

This is a little long so I posted it [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kDZN3rCfjQ/)

If more info is needed please ask me.

Update #1: `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Update #2: I had searched nearly every driver db that google told me, *none of them* included my model. But this is a 2018 laptop, not that antique, so why can't I find *anything* about it?

Update #3: `dmesg | grep -i video`

```
[    0.138785] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.319659] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.951453] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    1.068811] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[    1.069045] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:08/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
[    1.116118] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    1.116337] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input13
[    6.009940] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:670b)
[    6.064805] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    6.064806] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Comment: If it's integrated I wouldn't look at usb. Try `lspci` and report back to us.

Comment: Though I do find 0c45-670b, part of `lsusb`'s output, on [LinuxHardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0c45-670b) and the hardware listed there is exactly my modal.

Comment: Try `dmesg | grep -i video` or use microdia instead of video. We need to determinie if this is kernel based or simply a module.

Comment: This is old but read through anyway https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/hardware.html

Comment: Is it listed by `sudo lshw -c multimedia`  ?

Comment: @nobody It is. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tpf9rsq58R/)

Comment: @darth_epoxy I had run `modprobe uvcvideo` with no use

Comment: Please can you poste `lsmod`also?

Comment: @nobody [lsmod](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bNQ68FsfzD/)

Comment: sigh I can not find it https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-new/admin-guide/gspca-cardlist.html?highlight=0c45 here

Comment: @nobody so what should I do now?

Comment: This is from 2018 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235628

Comment: @darth_epoxy The main problem of that archlinux forum thread is about uvc1.5, but mine is a uvc 1.0.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Though after several reboots and whatnot, I do get an output for `dmesg | grep -i video` now, [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pQ2v8WMM5H/)

Comment: Bugger. Well this indicates that is is afirmware issue https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-xps-13-9370-Webcam-support/td-p/6032049/page/3 AND THEN this indicates that it could be related to the kernel version https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0c45-670b sorry we can't pinpoint it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: It did not work. It seems that ffmpeg does not even think it is a video device. But cheese does light the light up (I'll attach `ffmpeg` output [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qKTKJ4fFps/))